# Shine bright or shine brightly?

Tags: word-usage

1. The moon shone bright like a diamond in the sky. 2. The full moon is shining bright in the sky. Why not they are brightly? Are they correct?

Comment: Hi Mathew K.J., your question is [off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) because it can be answered using commonly available resources (i.e. a free online dictionary like [this one](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bright)). Moreover, EL&U has a 'research requirement': you're supposed to show research you've done trying to find the answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bright), *bright* is not only an adjective but also an adverb, usually used with the verbs *burn* and *shine*. Therefore, both are correct. However, in speech *brightly* is almost always used over *bright*. (British English) *Bright* is mostly used in poetic, literary forms.

Comment: Maybe in ***your*** speech you only use *brightly*. Do you have any evidence that everybody else does as well? Americans tend to use flat adverbs like *bright* much more often than the English, and my impression (living in Massachusetts) is that it's quite common in speech here.

Comment: @PeterShor Moreover, Rihanna has made sure the phrase “shine bright like a diamond” is more or less fixed. “Shine brightly like a diamond” actually sounds borderline unacceptable to me.

Answer (score 0):

Both bright and brightly are fine. They are both adverbs but bright is an adjective.

You could even use them in one sentence:

> The sun shone brightly; its rays were so bright.

You wouldn't use brightly without a verb as it is an adverb, not an adjective and make no sense.

You wouldn't say:

> The sun is **brightly**

But as bright is an adjective, as well as an adverb so you could use:

> The sun is **bright**

So really it depends on the context and whether you already have a verb in the sentence.

In your examples, both would be correct.

> The moon **shone** brightly like a diamond in the sky.
>    The full moon is **shining** brightly in the sky.

I put the verb is bold. As there is a verb before brightly it can be used as an adverb and is correct.

Comment: 1. _To be_ is a verb so it’s not just “whether you already have a verb in the sentence”; and 2. The question is asking about sentences where _bright_ is used adverbially after the verb _shine_, which constellation you **don’t** mention at all.